# In django admin how do I add a field for the reverse side of a ManyToManyField

Tags: django, django-admin

I have two models, 'Product' and 'Range', to be linked by a many to many field. The 'Product' class is in an app I didn't write, so It can't be modified (I can edit the modeladmin for it tho). I want to have the 'Ranges' a 'Product' is in to be editable in the admin, and I want to do it with a FilteredSelectMultiple, not inline admin.

simplified 'models.py':

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    #etc...
    #I can't modify this class

class Range(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, related_name='ranges')
```

and admin.py:

```
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # What do I put here to get a multi-select box for ranges?
    # Preferrably with one of those 'add' buttons to popup a window
    # to add ranges.
```

If I could modify Products I could put a ManyToManyField on it using the existing through table, and this works fine, but as stated I can't (or won't as it'll make upgrades to the external app a real pain).

Thanks in advance for any help! (PS I hope its easy to see here why I don't want to use inline admin forms - it makes the UI unnecessarily complex).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry it may be a little late, but anyone googling may benefit from this answer. It's not so easy, but it is feasible. You have to build your own form (which may descend from the existing form, if you want), and then manually load and save items.

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin

class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # <- your own fields declaration
    ranges = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        label='Ranges',
        queryset=Range.objects.all(),
        required=False,
        widget=admin.widgets.FilteredSelectMultiple("ranges", is_stacked=False))

    class Meta:
        model = Product


class MyProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        # Save first to obtain id
        super(MyProductAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
        # Clean and re-add related objects
        obj.range_set.clear()
        for range in form.cleaned_data['ranges']:
             obj.range_set.add(range)

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        if obj:
            ProductForm.base_fields['ranges'].initial = [o.pk for o in obj.range_set.all()]
        else:
            ProductForm.base_fields['ranges'].initial = []
        return ProductForm

# unregister and register again
admin.site.unregister(Product)
admin.site.register(Product, MyProductAdmin)
```

Comment: Much appreciated, I came up with something similar, was going to post it as an answer but real life got in the way.